# Unable to verify the first certificate - WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, postman, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager

I tried to use the Postman collection of WSO2 API Manager to work with APIs, but it didn't work fine and it return for all API 404 Not Found ,when i try to click on the red button it shows the error "Unable to verify the first certificate" .

[image: screenshot of postman console]

Comment: What is your API Manager version?

Comment: My API Manager version is 4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Postman settings and try disabling SSL Certificate Verification.

[image]

---

**Update**

It seems you are using the wrong version of the API. The publisher Rest API version for API Manager 4.1 is v3. Can you try downloading the collection from [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/reference/product-apis/publisher-apis/publisher-v3/publisher-v3/#section/Try-out-in-Postman).

Comment: I already did this step and still face the same problem

Comment: @OussamaNairi Can you open the Console tab in Postman on the bottom-left and add the request and response details to the question?

Comment: done, i added a screenshot of the console tab.

Comment: @OussamaNairi Check the update, you seem to be using the wrong API version.